# Error - It is not possible to check-out a shared item

Tags: 2011

I am randomly facing below error while checking out the component in SDL Tridion 2013.

> ***Error***   - It is not possible to check-out a shared item
>
> ***Stack Trace -*** at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnCheckingOut(CheckOutEventArgs eventArgs)
>       at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.CheckOut(LockType lockType, Boolean completeTransactionOnFailure)
>       at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.CheckOut(Boolean permanentLock)
>       at RREvent_System.MainClass.ProcessCaseStudyPageForPublish(Page page, TcmUri pubTargUri) in e:\EventSystem\MainClass.cs:line 627

I have written code like below.

```
 //component is type of Component
 if (component.IsCheckedOut)
 {
    component.CheckIn(true);
 }

 component.CheckOut(true);

 //Code to update component fiedls

 component.Save(true);     
 component.CheckIn(true);
```

Pls help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to checkout an item which is a shared.

To overcome this, you need to check an item is shared then localize and checkout an item.

Comment: Or edit the component from the "Owning" Publication instead, if you don't want to localize it.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably trying to check out a component that is blueprinted from a higher publication. You should check to see if its shared before checking it out:

```
if (component.IsShared)
{
   //either ignore, or check the component out in the owning publication (component.OwningRepository)
}
```